# How To Display Youtube Video Thumbnail?

Tags: android-youtube-api

I have a fragment with a ScrollView and I want to display the YouTube thumbnail of a video as one of the items in the scrollview.
I looked up everywhere but couldn't understand how to, I really need the base.

Please help me, I'm stuck like this for days...

This method supposed to take the VIDEO_ID(from YouTube) and take it's thumbnail.
This thumnbail should be displayed in youTubeThumbnailView.
Here is something I tried:

```
   public void getThumbnail(){
    String VIDEO_ID = "xxxxxx";
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView = new YouTubeThumbnailView(getActivity());
    youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView)youTubeThumbnailView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    youTubeThumbnailView.//Dont know how to continue :(.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [updated version of the youtube-android](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) sdk (version 1.2.1 released on 22 Jan 2015).

The changelog states something interesting about thumnails:

*The YouTubeThumbnailLoader interface's documentation has been updated to note that you must call the interface's release() method when you are finished with the YouTubeThumbnailLoader. The documentation for the YouTubeThumbnailView class also mentions this requirement.*